# Cannot use datetime.datetime.strptime, got an AttributeError instead

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have two strings in python.

```
time_array1='09-JAN-2014 01:19'
time_array2='09-JAN-2014 01:01'
```

I need to find the time difference and I am doing:

```
print time_array1
print time_array2
FMT = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'
datetime_object1= datetime.datetime.strptime(time_array1, FMT)
print datetime_object1
datetime_object2= datetime.datetime.strptime(time_array2, FMT)
print datetime_object2
diff=datetime_object1 - datetime_object2
print diff
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
    datetime_object1= datetime.datetime.strptime(time_array1, FMT)
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'
```

Is there any alternative way through which I can do it. It seems the python library doesn't have `strptime` attribute.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? The function was added in Python 2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strptime` method was added in python 2.5; if you are using an older version use the following code instead:

```
import datetime, time
datetime_object1 = datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(time_array1, FMT)[:6])
```

Your months are abbreviations, use the `%b` to parse that instead of `%m`.

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime, time
>>> time_array1='09-JAN-2014 01:19'
>>> time_array2='09-JAN-2014 01:01'
>>> FMT = '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M'
>>> datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(time_array1, FMT)[:6])
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 9, 1, 19)
>>> datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(time_array2, FMT)[:6])
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 9, 1, 1)
```

Comment: The time_array1 and timearray2 are not constant. The code wherein I'll take the insert_ts from database and take the difference between two consecutive insert_ts. So time_array1 and time_array2 will be changing. Now when I did datetime_object1=datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(time_array1, FMT)[:6]) I got 2014-03-21 12:04:00 and and when I did datetime_object2= datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(time_array2, FMT)[:6]) I got 2014-03-21 12:12:00 and I did the diff which gave me 0:08:00 but I got an error in script saying :  ValueError: time data did not match format:  data=X X  fmt=%d-%b-%Y %H:%M

Comment: Looks like you have data in your database that is not consistent. Either there is a row that uses a different format or is not a date altogether. Try catching the exception and printing the string that caused the parse to fail.

Comment: Yes got the error. some of the data is coming as 'X X' as part of the insert_ts.

Comment: Clearly that's not a value that can be pasted into a `datetime` object. You'll need to adjust your code to skip those.